# Formula expanded field and rounding cannot figure out

Tags: mysql, rounding

I have the following formula to put into mySQL

```
SELECT Order_Number, 
Order_Date, 
Product, 
Quantity, 
Price, 
Commission, 
Employee_Sold, 
(Quantity*Price)*(Commission*.01) AS Commision_Paid 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

The commission paid amount comes out with 2.992500 as one example.....

The commission field is setup as decimal(5,2).

In the expanded field (Commission_Paid) it would be nice for it to show up as 2.99 in this case.

I have tried the ROUND function in many places but I am not sure as I keep getting error messages.

Thanks in advance.  Student here and deadline on my paper.  Appreciated.

MySQL 5.5X running.

Comment: show your error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Round(x, 2)

```
SELECT Order_Number, 
Order_Date, 
Product, 
Quantity, 
Price, 
Commission, 
Employee_Sold, 
round((Quantity*Price)*(Commission*.01), 2) AS Commision_Paid 
FROM Orders 
WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```